# .htaccess for multiple rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I wanted to create an htaccess file to remove the `.php` extension and change `course.php?id=1` to `course/1`. But that does not seem to work out. Can any one correct my htaccess?(I am quite new to writing htaccess files)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# If request is for a file that does actually exist, don't rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # If request is for a directory that does actually exist, don't rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/course/(.*)$ /course.php?id=$1 [NC]

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it this way:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^course/([^/]+)/?$ course.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/$2.php [L]
```

Comment: What if i wanted to add 2 more rewrite rules for subcourse.php and lesson.php? Can I just copy and paste them below the course.php rewrite rule, just changing the required fields?